# which circuitbreaker is better for service calls handling in Python - circuitbreaker vs pybreaker?

Tags: python, microservices, circuit-breaker

I have found 2 libraries for circuit breaker in python - https://github.com/fabfuel/circuitbreaker and https://github.com/danielfm/pybreaker. Both of these have average ratings and I am looking for something like Hystrix for python. Is there any other popular open source circuit breaker tool for python?